# Can't pass array to Livewire component with <livewire> element, only with Blade directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm passing a `$classes` array, defined as a public property in my Livewire controller, to my Livewire component. When I use the blade directive:

```html
@livewire('admin.syllabi', ['classes' => $classes, 'page' => $page, 'type' => 'syllabus', 'searchFields' => 'title, description'])
```

I can access my `$classes` array. However, when I use the livewire element:

```html
<livewire:admin.syllabi
        page="{{ $page }}"
        type="syllabus"
        searchFields="title, description"
        classes="{{ $classes }}"
    />
```

I get the error,

> htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given.

I tried using : in front of the "classes" attribute in the  element but then I get a different error:

> "syntax error, unexpected token "<"

Has anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass in variables or PHP expressions into the component using the "component syntax" `<livewire:... />`, you'll have to prefix the property with `:`, then it'll be parsed as a PHP expression like this,

```html
<livewire:admin.syllabi
    :page="$page"
    type="syllabus"
    searchFields="title, description"
    :classes="$classes"
/>
```

This is a part of Blade and not limited to Livewire, as described in the official documentation, see the link below.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#passing-data-to-components

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is related to passing the $classes array to your Livewire component using the livewire directive. When using the livewire directive, you can pass data directly to the component's public properties, but passing an array using the syntax you provided can cause the issue you're facing.

Here's the correct way to pass the $classes array to your Livewire component using the livewire directive:

```
<livewire:admin.syllabi
    :page="$page"
    type="syllabus"
    searchFields="title, description"
    :classes="$classes"
/>
```

Note the use of the colon (:) before the page and classes attributes. This indicates that you're binding these attributes to the component's public properties, which allows Livewire to correctly handle them as data passed to the component.

In your Livewire component, make sure you have a public property named $classes declared like this:

```
public $classes;
```

By using the correct binding syntax, you should be able to pass the $classes array to your Livewire component without encountering any issues.

Comment: You don't actually need there to be a matching public property, you can accept it as a parameter to the mount method and do anything with it from there. It does make sense to have it, but it'll work without it too. Also, the colon does not bind to public properties like you've described, but let's Blade interpert and pass the value as a PHP expression rather than a plain string. The binding to public properties happens with Livewire magic, the colon is Blade syntax